# Avoid uninstalling unsigned android application before installing the signed version

Tags: android, installation, signed

I was testing a signed version of a test application. But when I try to overwrite the previous installation, the installer reports "Application not installed".

I have interesting info in the application SharedPreferences and I was wondering if there is any way to avoid uninstalling my previous unsigned version losing my SharedPreferences.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this from the terminal:

```
adb shell pm uninstall -k your.package.name.here
```

That should uninstall your app but leave behind its data. Then when you install the signed version your preferences will be intact.